# port scanning with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm learning how to scan ports using Python and the `socket` module.

This is what I've got:

```
import socket, sys

def check_ports_socket(ip, portlist):
    try:
        for port in portlist:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.settimeout(5)
            result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
            if result == 0:
                print(f'Port {port}: \t Open')
            else:
                print(f'Port {port}: \t Closed')
            sock.close()
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
        print('Connection Error')
        sys.exit()

check_ports_socket('localhost', [80, 8080, 443, 9999])
```

The problem is that I deliberately opened port 80 and 9999 to see if the code really works and for both of them it returns 'closed' ?

Can anyone explain ?

Comment: What exactly does this mean "I deliberately opened port 80 and 9999"? If netstat -an does not return info for these ports, you have not "opened" them.

Comment: That means that I ran `sudo ufw allow 80` and 9999.

Comment: That means nothing if you don't have a server servicing those ports...

Comment: Ohh .... so opening the ports does nothing to port scanning unless I actually service those ports.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 80` is not opening port, it is allowing the port to be connected

Comment: OK, ok that makes much more sense now. Thank you. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll tick it for you.